# Validation in Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, nhibernate-validator

I want to use Hibernate Validator, In first step I checked and studied the following reference :

- [Hibernate Validator JSR 349 Reference Implementation Reference Guide 5.0.2.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_validator_reference.pdf)

first sample in page 3 is my problem

I cloud not find this imports packages (javax.validation.*)

in hibernate-validator-5.0.2.Final.jar

I found only (org.hibernate.validator.*) but these classes did not exist

```
package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter01;

import java.util.Set;
// ?????
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation; // Not Found 
import javax.validation.Validation; // Not Found 
import javax.validation.Validator; // Not Found 
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory; // Not Found 
// ?????
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class CarTest {

    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        // ?????
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
        // ?????
    }

    @Test
    public void manufacturerIsNull() {
        Car car = new Car(null, "DD-AB-123", 4);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations
                = validator.validate(car);
        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("may not be null", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());

}
```

please help me and guide me what is necessary packages for the following code ?

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = factory.getValidator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [validation-api jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22validation-api%22) to your classpath. The latest version is `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar`. The classes `javax.validation.*` are contained in this jar.

Comment: Can I use Hibernate Validation without this jar ??? or I must have it for any hibernate validation ???

Comment: No, it is required. It contains the Bean Validation API, and Hibernate Validation is an implementation of this API.